# how can I count "CREATE GPL" in this case?

Tags: java, string

My DB generates 3000 lines for each process and I must count some values for a report.
the generated file is like this :

```
CREATE TTL:NAME=SMO:0/TTS:0/UPL:1,BLQ=TRUE,NAND:TRUE,EBSPWRC=ADAPTIVE,EMSPWRC=ADAPTIVE
CREATE GPL,ASSLAPD=TSM:37/LPDLM:0,
CREATE GPL,ASSLAPD=TSM:38/LPDLM:5,
CREATE GPL,ASSLAPD=TSM:41/LPDLM:1,
CREATE GPL,ASSLAPD=TSM:21/LPDLM:8,
CREATE TTL:NAME=SMO:0/TTS:0/UPL:1,BLQ=FALSE,NAND:FALSE,EBSPWRC=ADAPTIVE,EMSPWRC=ADAPTIVE
CREATE GPL,ASSLAPD=TSM:37/LPDLM:4,
CREATE GPL,ASSLAPD=TSM:21/LPDLM:1,
CREATE TTL:NAME=SMO:0/TTS:0/UPL:1,BLQ=TRUE,NAND:TRUE,EBSPWRC=ADAPTIVE,EMSPWRC=ADAPTIVE
CREATE GPL,ASSLAPD=TSM:38/LPDLM:1,
CREATE GPL,ASSLAPD=TSM:41/LPDLM:1,
CREATE GPL,ASSLAPD=TSM:21/LPDLM:7,
```

Actually I want to count `CREATE GPL` if the `BLQ` and `NAND` be true,
Also I wrote this method that read the file line by line :

```
public void getGPLCount(File f) throws Exception { 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.startsWith("CREATE TTL:NAME=") && line.contains("BLQ=TRUE") && line.contains("NAND:TRUE"))
        //___//
    }
}
```

thnaks for your help ...

Comment: So what is the question actually? Why doesn't your code work?

Comment: I want to search it in 3000 lines but it returns wrong ! maybe need to use indexOf method for create GPL but how ?

Comment: do you want to count the lines following each "CREATE TTL:NAME" with BLQ=TRUE and NAND:TRUE separately?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain clearly what isn't working or what is the difficulty that you're having.

Comment: You say it returns wrong. How? The code you've shown us has no counting whatsoever. We can't tell what your error is because you've erased that bit of code. Please be patient with us: It's difficult to answer without knowing whether or not we're violating your homework assignment's intent.

Comment: dear @ccoakley it was funny, homework or assignment ?!?! I have just a small problem with this : how to continue the loop to count the bottom lines !!!!

Comment: It's not particularly funny. The question is tagged homework. As far as we know, the point of the assignment is to see if you can do conditional counting within an iteration context. It's also not particularly difficult, so the fact that you are having difficulty with the task indicates that it might actually be the point of the assignment.

Comment: @ccoakley I think someone tagged it homework for Mike

Comment: thanks dear @soulcheck yes the Matthew Farwell tagged it :( I don't know why ??!

Comment: Sonova.... Then I'd have posted the answer. Sorry Mike. I'll post.

Comment: @MikeRedford: Ok, I think I've posted what you wanted. And since I badgered you about homework (glad someone removed the tag), I promise to update if you can specify any problems with my snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if Thomas's answer is close, but misunderstood what you wanted. I'm just modifying his snippet.

Something like this:

```
int counter = 0;
boolean countLines = false;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  if (line.startsWith("CREATE TTL:NAME=") && line.contains("BLQ=TRUE") && line.contains("NAND:TRUE")) {
    countLines = true;
  } else if (line.startsWith("CREATE TTL:NAME=") && !(line.contains("BLQ=TRUE") || line.contains("NAND:TRUE"))){
    countLines = false;
  } else if( line.startsWith("CREATE GPL") && countLines )  {
    counter++;
  }
}
```

So start counting every time we get BOTH BLQ=true AND Nand=true, and stop the counter if we get a TTL line missing one (or both) of those. Is this the logic you want?

UPDATE:

Matthew's solution is also correct, but in pseudocode. Translating to Java:

```
int counter = 0;
boolean countLines = false;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  // test for TTL line
  if (line.startsWith("CREATE TTL:NAME=")) { 
    countLines = (line.contains("BLQ=TRUE") && line.contains("NAND:TRUE"))
  // if TTL told us to count and it's a GPL line
  } else if(countLines && line.startsWith("CREATE GPL"))  {
    counter++;
  }
}
```

His answer is cleaner because he doesn't duplicate the `startsWith("CREATE TTL:NAME=")` like I did. In my defense, I was trying to get you a working java example and Thomas was extremely close to what you wanted.

Comment: rep++; thanks, Actually at first I wrote it with FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f);
            byte b[] = new byte[fi.available()];
            fi.read(b);
            String text = new String(b); but it was very slow, so I use br.readLine() method.

Comment: Thanks (and sorry for the misunderstanding). The readline() method was not my idea. That was taken from Thomas. I just updated his code to match the comments you left on why his solution wasn't correct (actually, the comment you left on Matthew's answer was the most helpful as it provided the correct answer).

Comment: No problem bud! ,As I wrote before realine() is my idea, but unfortunately I can't understand the mattew's answer, could you please explain it for me?

Comment: I updated my answer with the Java version of matthew's answer. Does seeing it in Java help?

Answer (score 1):

In pseudocode:

```
public void getGPLCount(File f) throws Exception { 
    for each line {
        if (line is a TTL line) {
            countIt = (if BLQ && NAND);
        } else {  
            if (countIt && is GPL line) {
                // we count it, increment count
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("count=" + count);
}
```

Comment: No I want to count the "CREATE GPL" for example in this case we have 7

Comment: This does count the CREATE GPL. Are there other types of line that you're not showing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might set some flag to true when you encounter a line with `BLQ` and `NAND`, set it to false when you encounter a line without `BLQ`, `NAND` or `CREATE GPL` and count if the line starts with `CREATE GPL` and the flag is true.

Something like this:

```
int counter = 0;
boolean countLines = false;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  if (line.startsWith("CREATE TTL:NAME=") && line.contains("BLQ=TRUE") && line.contains("NAND:TRUE")) {
    countLines = true;
  } else if( line.startsWith("CREATE GPL") && countLines )  {
    counter++;
  } else {
    countLines = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but how to continue the line, in your code the line returns just "CREATE TTL:NAME=" line so we can't check bottom lines, how can I continue the loop ???

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you need to actually count each block after the condition is me separately.

You're almost there:

```
public List<Integer> getGPLCount(File f) throws Exception { 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line;
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int count = 0;

    boolean counting = false; // are we counting in this iteration
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.startsWith("CREATE GPL")) { //BLOCK DELIMITER
            if (counting) { //WE WERE COUNTING UNTIL NOW, SO WE'RE ADDING THE COUNTER TO THE RESULT LIST AND STOP COUNTING 
                result.add(count);
                count = 0;
                counting = false;
            }
            if (line.startsWith("CREATE TTL:NAME=") && line.contains("BLQ=TRUE") && line.contains("NAND:TRUE")) {//WE START COUNTING

                counting = true;
            } 
        } else { // WE'RE INSIDE THE BLOCK, SO IF WE'RE COUNTING, WE COUNT
            if (counting) {
                ++count;
            }
        }

    }
if (counting) { //TAKE CARE OF WHAT'S LEFT
    result.add(count);

}

    br.close();
    return result;
}
```

If you need to count all lines, just remove the result list and all references and don't reinitialize the counter.

Comment: rep++ , Thanks a lot but it count BLQ=TRUE for me, instead of CREATE GPL, why?